# Docker nginx+php-fpm ttfb is slow compared to bare metal

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, docker-compose

I have nginx and php-fpm running in separate docker containers. Php-fpm processs the same php script in as fast time as php-fpm running on bare-metal (not using docker). However, the TTFB when using nginx+php-fpm docker is always over 1.3 seconds, whereas running nginx+php-fpm on bare metal (no docker) TTFB is always < 30 ms.

Why is nginx (presumably) so slow on docker? More importantly, I'm sure this is a configuration issue that can be resolved, what in my docker-compose yml needs to be changed to improve the performance of nginx TTFB? No one would use docker for nginx+php-fpm if this is the expected behavior so I know this is user error.

Edit: I've created a repo you can see all files and try for yourself. The numbers on TTFB will be slightly different than the app I'm referring to, but issue still exists, See [CI Docker Test Repo](https://github.com/Zelfapp/ci-docker).

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads:/var/www/uploads
    networks:
      - www
  php:
    user: "${userid}:${groupid}"
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server/php-fpm
    env_file:
      - server/php-fpm/env/my.env
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${ipaddr}
      CI_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads:/var/www/uploads
    networks:
      - www

networks:
  www:
```

### Issue solved (I'll leave up in case anyone else runs into this)

I've been starting docker using this command:

```
userid=$(id -u) groupid=$(id -g) ipaddr=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}') docker-compose up --build
```

In docker-compose.yml in the php container you see `XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${ipaddr}`

The problem was, `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'` does not return the ip on all systems. So xdebug was getting the incorrect ip address, which in turn was causing a syscall that was causing the latency. Once I sent in the correct ip address to xdebug, all was well.

I adjusted my `up` command to simply pass in the ip rather than trying to pass in a dynamic lookup, since it is different on every system. Now latency is gone.

```
userid=$(id -u) groupid=$(id -g) ipaddr=$(myipaddress) docker-compose up --build
```

**TTFB running nginx+php-fpm in docker 1.23 seconds:**

[image: TTFB running nginx+php-fpm in docker 1.23 seconds:]

**TTFB bare metal not in docker:**

[image: ttfb bare metal nginx+php-fpm (not in docker)]

**php script timer running php-fpm on docker container:**

[image: php script timer]

**php script timer running php-fpm on bare metal (not in docker)**

[image: php script timer running php-fpm on bare metal (not in docker)]

Comment: Hi. I don't have a solution to your problem, but I do have my own use-case experience with nginx+php-fpm in Docker. Currently we run php-fpm 7.2 and recently upgraded to 7.4. TTFB is usually around 200ms. But that was the same before migrating to Docker. I use a custom php-fpm image built on top of `centos:centos7.6.1810` and use the official `nginx:1.14.2` base image. Your nginx configs will play a big role in how the stack behaves. Regarding your DNS hack: That's very non-docker way of doing things, all your info should be FED INTO the starting container rather than using it to generate cfg

Comment: Hey @zelf, how did you go about tracking the issue down, as my TTFB is 100ms on production and 6.3 secs in docker setup as above.

Comment: @William I don't know what you're setup is, but if you're using my setup then this is how I tracked down the issue and fixed it: I adjusted my `up` command to simply pass in the ip rather than trying to pass in a dynamic lookup, since it is different on every system. Now latency is gone. Make sure you're passing in your correct local ipv4 address.